# Using strchr() in dev c++, invalid conversion from 'char' to 'int'[-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, string, dev-c++, strchr

i want the character founded by what i'm input to to find it so here's the code, but it's always error in "hasil=strchr(str,karakter);". it's says "invalid conversion from 'char' to 'int'[-fpermissive]"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    char str[100];
    char karakter[50];
    char *hasil;
    hasil=strchr(str,karakter);

    cout<<"Input String : "; gets(str);
    cout<<"Input Karakter : "; gets(karakter);
    printf("\nResult : %s\n",hasil);
    printf("karakter %c founded in index %d",karakter,(hasil-str));
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Double check how the function works: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strchr

Comment: Also you need to call `strchr` after you get input, otherwise it is meaningless.

Comment: I think `strstr(str, karakter)` would be more appropriate, as both inputs are strings. `strchr()` looks for a *single character* and as usual, `int` is used for that character in library functions. Perhaps you meant to check the *first character* as in `strchr(str, *karakter)`.

Comment: [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) Further using the iostream for output, why would you then turn around and call `gets()` for input? Are you intentionally mixing C/C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's multiple problem in your code.

1. strchr takes a `char *` as first argument and a `char` as second argument, you gave a `char *` instead. Here is the manual http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html
2. You should be putting the function call `strchr` after both `gets` to initialize both `str` and `karakter`
3. You should be using `fgets` instead of `gets`, your program would be killed if the user inputs overflows your buffers

After the modification it should look like this

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    using namespace std;

    int main(void){
        char str[100];
        char karakter;
        char *hasil;

        cout<<"Input String : "; fgets(str, 100, stdin);
        cout<<"Input Karakter : "; fgets(&karakter, 1, stdin);
        hasil = strchr(str,karakter);
        printf("\nResult : %s\n",hasil);
        printf("karakter %c founded in index %d",karakter,(hasil-str));
        getch();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Probably a typo: *a `char` as second argument*. `strchr`'s second argument is an `int`

Comment: Yes, but the int will be truncated to a char for comparison, as to not misleads people, char is a better way to describe the function

Comment: Thank you all, you all saved me